# SQL Server, select statement in case

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with below details

```
SESSIONID  NODEID SEQUENCE STVID STARTTIME               ENDTIME
4000025502 2      0        2     2016-08-02 19:31:52.000 2016-08-02 19:44:01.000
4000026291 2      0        3     2016-08-06 10:20:19.000 2016-08-06 10:33:03.000
4000025219 2      0        1     2016-08-01 20:30:13.000 2016-08-01 20:37:01.000
4000026331 2      0        4     2016-08-07 13:22:24.000 2016-08-07 13:53:36.000
```

Now while selecting this record I want to add another column **"Status"**,
Now for this **"Status"** column I want to check "**STARTTIME**" is present in Calendar table.

> CALENDAR TABLE:

```
DATE ID DATESTART               DATEEND                 APPLICATION
1       2016-08-02 00:00:00.000 2016-08-02 23:59:59.000 ALL
2       2016-09-04 00:00:00.000 2016-09-04 23:59:59.000 ALL
3       2016-09-10 00:00:00.000 2016-09-10 23:59:59.000 ALL
```

The way it should be here is if **"STARTTIME"** is between **"DATESTART"** and **"DATEEND"** then **"STATUS"** column should be 1 else 0.

The solution should be like below.

> UPDATED: SOLUTION REQUIRED

```
SESSIONID  NODEID SEQUENCE STVID STARTTIME               STATUS
4000025502 2      0        2     2016-08-02 19:31:52.000 1
4000026291 2      0        3     2016-08-06 10:20:19.000 0
4000025219 2      0        1     2016-08-01 20:30:13.000 0
4000026331 2      0        4     2016-08-07 13:22:24.000 0
```

How can I do this with Case statement or is there any other way do it.

Thanks

Comment: Join to the Calendar table, having your between condition be the join predicate?

Comment: Provide your desired result with above input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this query

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN   Exists(SELECT 1 FROM CalendarTable c 
                           WHERE y.Starttime BETWEEN c.DateStart AND c.DateEnd)  
                    THEN 1
             ELSE 0                 
        END  AS [Status]
From YourDataTable y
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use a case expression this quite easily.

```
SELECT STATUS = case when STARTTIME > DATESTART AND STARTTIME < DATEEND then 1 else 0 end
From YourTable
```

Comment: Here STARTTIME is in one table and DATESTART  and DATEEND is in other table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way

```
select CASE 
    WHEN STARTTIME BETWEEN DATESTART AND DATEEND THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS Status From table
```

Comment: Here STARTTIME is in one table and DATESTART and DATEEND is in other table